# Create and update multiple records in has_many :through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

Don't know if I am heading the right direction, but lacking knowledge in web-development stops me from doing the following task:

```
In the application a user can setup settings which is an object. In the setting component 
we can subscribe or unsubscribe users from notifications To simplify the task for users 
and increase UX we decided to put all notifications on one form.
```

I believe that should be possible in `Rails-3.2.8`.

So we have

```
class Setting

  has_many :notifications, :through => :email_notifications
  has_many :email_notifications
```

```
class Notification
  attr_accessible :name, :primary, :secondary

  has_many :settings, :through => :email_notifications
  has_many :email_notifications
```

```
class EmailNotification
  attr_accessible :notification_id, :setting_id, :primary, :secondary
  belongs_to :notification
  belongs_to :setting
```

In the `settings_controller` instantiate all notificatoins and pass id to rich join association:

```
def new
  @setting = Setting.new
  @notifications = Notification.all
  @notifications.each do |n|
    @setting.email_notifications.build(:notification_id => n.id)
  end
```

Then I stuck in the view (all solutions are not workable, but I list them anyway, so you might comment on the solution and where it went wrong):

**SOLUTION #1**

```
<%= form_for @setting, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
<div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :email_periods, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
        <%= f.select :email_periods, ["Daily", "Weekly", "Tuesdays & Thursdays"], :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><%= 'Notification' %></th>
            <th><%= 'Primary' %></th>
            <th><%= 'Secondary' %></th>
            <th><%= 'Reminder interval' %></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% @setting.email_notifications.each do |s| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= s.notification.name.to_s.humanize %></td>
            <td><%= check_box 'setting[notification_ids]', :primary %></td>
            <td><%= check_box 'setting[notification_ids]', :secondary %></td>
            <td><%= 'possible ddl' %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
    settings_path, :class => 'btn' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

But it gives me back a check_box with the name setting[notification_ids] which is actually unusable.

Then I thought to create a form for email_notifications:

**SOLUTION #2**

```
<%= form_for @setting.email_notifications do |s| %>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><%= 'Notification' %></th>
            <th><%= 'Primary' %></th>
            <th><%= 'Secondary' %></th>
            <th><%= 'Reminder interval' %></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% @setting.email_notifications.each do |s| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= s.notification.name.to_s.humanize %></td>
            <td><%= f.check_box s.primary %></td>
            <td><%= f.check_box s.secondary %></td>
            <td><%= 'possible ddl' %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
<%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %></br>
<% end %>
```

but then again it shoots me with an error:
`undefined method email_notification_..._email_notification_email_notification_email_notifications_path for #<#<Class:0x007f86942d16e0>:0x007f86979e02d0>`

Then I decided to have a form_for and build each `email_notification` inside that form:

```
<%= form_for @setting.email_notifications.build do |s| %>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><%= 'Notification' %></th>
            <th><%= 'Primary' %></th>
            <th><%= 'Secondary' %></th>
            <th><%= 'Reminder interval' %></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% @setting.email_notifications.each do |s| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= s.notification.name.to_s.humanize %></td>
            <td><%= f.check_box s.primary %></td>
            <td><%= f.check_box s.secondary %></td>
            <td><%= 'possible ddl' %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
<%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %></br>
<% end %>
```

But again an error:

```
undefined method `email_notifications_path' for #:0x007f86979e02d0>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

P.S. By some reason StackOverflow didn't recognize ruby style inheritance `<` that's why I had to remove from the examples.